# Unity Reflection probe rotating

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi guys is it possible to rotate the yellow cube(Box projection bounds) outside the reflection probe.I tried to rotate with Transform component but nothing happened when I rotated it.[Pictures of the yellow cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiSVf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, as mentioned in [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/rotating-reflection-probe.276509/) Unity Forum post.

> It's not something that's currently supported and may not be due to the extra shader complexity for what is probably an uncommon use case.

There is a [Unity Feedback Idea](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/reflection-probes-rotating) regarding this problem, which means that the Unity Team will maybe implement it in the future.